# Convert VB to C# help (? operator)

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'd appreciate some help with converting the following VB code to C#. Code converters have worked fine so far but with this part I've sorta hit a brickwall and I don't know how to solve it.

```
For Y As Integer = 0 To If(Flip, 1, 3)
...
Next
```

I thought this would work at first:

```
for (int Y = 0; (Y <= Convert.ToInt32(Flip)) ? 1 : 3; Y++)
   {
   ...
   }
```

But alas it doesn't. Maybe I'm just at a loss but I'm not sure how to proceed here.

Thanks for any suggestions!

**EDIT:**

Flip is a boolean. The converter suggested

```
for (int Y = 0; Y <= Flip ? 1 : 3; Y++)
```

which resulted in *Operator <= cannot be applied to operands of type int and bool*. Hence why I tried to convert. The conversion however resulted in *Can't implicitly convert int to bool* or the other way round.

**SOLUTION:**

Brackets around Flip ? 1: 3 seem to have solved the problem. So the convert appears to have been right except for one small detail.

`for (int Y = 0; Y <= (Flip ? 1 : 3); Y++)`

Thanks all!

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What is the type of `Flip`, why are you converting it `ToInt32` and what compiler or runtime errors do you get?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use

```
(Flip ? 1 : 3)
```

instead. Both VB's [`If` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb513985.aspx) and the [`?:` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ty67wk28.aspx) in C# require the first operand to be a boolean. So in your case `Flip` already must be a boolean, which you don't have to convert to an integer at all to use it in the conditional operator.

Comment: Also the result of the `?` [should be cached](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29489981/11683) into a variable if `Flip` changes.

Comment: The converter suggested `for (int Y = 0; Y <= Flip ? 1 : 3; Y++)` which resulted in _Operator <= cannot be applied to operands of type int and bool_. Hence why I tried to convert. Your suggestion results in the same error, the_lotus.

Comment: Brackets around Flip ? 1: 3 seem to have solved the problem, as pointed out below. Thanks all! `for (int Y = 0; Y <= (Flip ? 1 : 3); Y++)`

Answer (score 3):

Note that in VB, the bounds of a `For ... Next` are computed once, just before the looping begins. If there's any chance that `Flip` could change during the loop, then that may explain the difference.

To re-iterate, the C# equivalent of a VB `For ... Next` looks like this (very pedantic) code:

```
{
    // y1 is the hidden variable/register that retains the ending bound of the range
    int y1 = Flip ? 1 : 3; // Or whatever - what is Flip again? Here as Boolean
    // int y1 = (Flip != 0) ? 1 : 3; // Flip as Integer
    for(int Y=0; Y<=y1; Y++)
    {
        // ...
    } 
}
```

Comment: @the_lotus - quite right, crazy how the C# didn't come out anywhere near right in the OP (converter error? human desperation?). If Flip is Boolean, then really it's (Flip ? 1 : 3) as others have said. If Flip is Integer, then it could be ((Flip != 0) ? 1 : 3).

Comment: Thanks rskar, I think the brackets solved the problem! `for (int Y = 0; Y <= (Flip ? 1 : 3); Y++)` appears to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (at least it's working for me):

```
for (int Y = 0; Y <= Flip ? 1 : 3; Y++) {
   // ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Y As Integer = 0
While If((Y <= Convert.ToInt32(Flip)), 1, 3)
  '.. Your Code
  Y += 1
End While
```